# How to display the error code from a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a Powershell script and display the error code and error message if it fails. It is supposed to output me a result in this format:

```
"FAILED;ErrorCode;ErrorMessage;"
```

Here is my script:

```
param([String]$Cab_Type)
$output

if(!(Test-Connection -Cn 165.100.10.10 -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -quiet))
{
$output = "FAILED; " + $LASTEXITCODE + ";" + $error[0] + ";"
}
else
{
$output = "PASSED"
}

Write-Host $Cab_Type
Write-Host "<ScriptResult_Start>"
Write-Host $output
Write-Host "<ScriptResult_End>"
```

I am trying to intentionally ping an address that I know will fail.
When running the script, it returns me the error message but not the error code.

Does $LASTEXITCODE not return the error code of the script? Even if my script worked, does it only return 0 or 1? Is there any way of getting the actual error code of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are after?

```
# set up a hash with possible Ping status codes
$status = @{
    11001 = 'Buffer Too Small'
    11002 = 'Destination Net Unreachable'
    11003 = 'Destination Host Unreachable'
    11004 = 'Destination Protocol Unreachable'
    11005 = 'Destination Port Unreachable'
    11006 = 'No Resources'
    11007 = 'Bad Option'
    11008 = 'Hardware Error'
    11009 = 'Packet Too Big'
    11010 = 'Request Timed Out'
    11011 = 'Bad Request'
    11012 = 'Bad Route'
    11013 = 'TimeToLive Expired Transit'
    11014 = 'TimeToLive Expired Reassembly'
    11015 = 'Parameter Problem'
    11016 = 'Source Quench'
    11017 = 'Option Too Big'
    11018 = 'Bad Destination'
    11032 = 'Negotiating IPSEC'
    11050 = 'General Failure'
}

$server = '165.100.10.10'
$ping   = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='$server'").StatusCode

if (!$ping -or [int]$ping -ne 0) {
    $err = if ( $status[[int]$ping]) { $status[[int]$ping] } else { "Unknown Failure" }
    $output = "FAILED; $ping; $err"

}
else { $output = "PASSED" }

Write-Host $output
```

The above example outputs:

> ```
> FAILED; 11010; Request Timed Out
> ```

Comment: Many thanks. As a beginner in Powershell, I do not really understand the line of code that you are assigning to $ping. Do you mind further explaining your code or referring me to other sources that can help me understand? I am also trying to get the same kind of script that returns me an error code and message but with other commands such as Get-NetAdapter.

Comment: @Komputer `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='$server'"` returns an object with multiple properties after performing a `ping` to the specified server name or IP address. The brackets around the command 'capture' this object and since we are only interested in the property `StatusCode`, we can simply use the 'dot' syntax to get that single property. It is in fact a shorthand code for `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='lambiek'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StatusCode`. To see the properties and methods of an object, pipe it through to `Get-Member`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle errors and verifying the. First and foremost, I would like you to keep the main code under a `try/catch` block and capture the error message so that you get to know what exactly the error is. Below is the modification of your code.

```
param([String]$Cab_Type)
$output
try
{
    if(!(Test-Connection -Cn 165.100.10.10 -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -quiet))
    {
    $output = "FAILED; " + $LASTEXITCODE + ";" + $error[0] + ";"
    }
    else
    {
    $output = "PASSED"
    }

    Write-Host $Cab_Type
    Write-Host "<ScriptResult_Start>"
    Write-Host $output
    Write-Host "<ScriptResult_End>"
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Also, go through about 1. [TRY CATCH FINALLY in PS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6)

Apart from that you can use `$Error` variable to get to know about all the errors.

Go through  2. [About $Error variable and how to use it effectively](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/)

Also you need to understand 3. [Powershell Exceptions and Everything you ever wanted to know](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/)

Hope it helps and gives you a direction.